# jQuery loop over JSON result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to reformat the result of string json  On the jQuery AJAX success callback I want to loop over the results of the object and change date type or format from string to date and value also like This is an example ,

```
var chartData1 = JSON.parse('[{"date":"2018-09-16T00:00:00","value":"10:02"},{"date":"2018-09-17T00:00:00","value":"10:37"},{"date":"2018-09-18T00:00:00","value":"10:25"}]');
```

I want to format to be like this format

```
var chartData1 = [{
    date: new Date(2018, 9, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    value: 10.2
}, {
    date: new Date(2018, 9, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    value: 10.37
}, {
    date: new Date(2018, 9, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    value: 10.25
},];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use array.map. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: do a foreach JSON.parse('[]').forEach((item)=>{console.log(item)}); and format date and value on each item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to modify the objects in the array like :

```js
var chartData1 = JSON.parse('[{"date":"2018-09-16T00:00:00","value":"10:02"},{"date":"2018-09-17T00:00:00","value":"10:37"},{"date":"2018-09-18T00:00:00","value":"10:25"}]');

var result = chartData1.map(e => ({
  date: new Date(e.date),
  value: e.value.replace(':', '.')
}))

console.log(result)
```